# PHP: any exceptions to line commenting?

Tags: php, syntax, comments

My code:

```
//  } elseif(php_uname() === TEST_SERVER_NAME){
//      $tmp = "/var/www/html/".preg_replace("/.*(demo[0-9]+).*/", '$1', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."/something/tmp/";
//  } else{
//      $tmp = '/var/www/html/something/tmp/';
//  }
```

My IDE (phstorm) highlights it as if something is not commented out, starting from the second line above.
Is it the case? Can *anything* break line commenting?

Comment: slashes can brake line commenting in some case, why dont you use /* */

Comment: Probably because unnamed "My ide" recognises `*/` as the end of a comment and is a bit lame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything following a `//` on a line is a comment until the end of the line. You *can* break out of `/* */` comments, you cannot break out of `//` comments before the end of the line.

Your IDE is bad. ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Maybe there's an open quote above which ends in your `'` or `"`?
- Maybe there's a `/*` above which ends in your `*/`?
- Maybe your IDE is wrong?